# Google Script - Google Sheets TimeZone Issue - how to convert visible data ignoring timezone formatting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am facing an issue with TimeZones in Google Scripts and Sheets. I want to ignore the GMG and read visible value of the cell.  When the new record with a new booking is created by Zapier, it inputs the date in a format like on picture

[image]

In 99,5% everything works fine, but in 0,5% of cases, while reading data input by the logger in Google scripts, It reads this date in Travel Date Col as "Sun Mar 26 23:00:00 GMT+01:00 2023" in row 3. In row 4 is  "Mon Mar 06 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2023".
I have also create sheet so you can see it in orginal formating: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bYqKQ8IFdYSW0HA9bAfHl3WDe_aqAngPlwbjkdQfk0c/edit#gid=1489258764

Data visible in sheets is always correct, but sometimes Zapiers put their different GMT. **I want to keep the original date and time visible in a row, ignoring the GMT formatting of the cell.** Good output should be:

- 2023-03-27, 00:00:00
  2023-03-06, 00:00:00

My current script work in a loop where "X" is a row number. It read to date and time and separates them do different cells.

```
   //@@ Check date @@
  
  var dateToFormat = newBookings.getRange("D"+x).getValue();
  var soloDate =  newBookings.getRange("E"+x).setValue(new Date(dateToFormat.setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('dd"-"mm"-"yy'); 

//@@ Check time @@
  if(time !== ""){
    var newTime = Utilities.formatDate(time, 'CET', 'HH:mm') // Format date
    if(newTime === "00:00"){
      newBookings.getRange("F"+x).setValue("")
    }
  }
```

What would you do to solve that issue and ignore GMT formating in scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your provided image and your expected values, you want to retrieve the values from column "D" of the sheet as follows.

  - From

    ```
      2023-03-27 00:00:00
      2023-03-06 00:00:00
    ```
  - To (In this case, you want to put the values of "2023-03-27" and "00:00:00" into columns "E" and "F", respectively.)

    ```
      2023-03-27, 00:00:00
      2023-03-06, 00:00:00
    ```

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "New Bokings"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("D2:D" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([d]) => d ? d.trim().split(" ") : Array(2).fill(null));
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is tested on your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks, that it! range.getDisplayValues() this was the right solution. Thanks again